# Julia: Vectorize function along a specific axis of a matrix

Tags: vector, julia, vectorization

What is the best way in Julia to vectorize a function along a specific axis? For example sum up all the rows of a matrix. Is it possible with the dot notation?

```
sum.(ones(4,4))
```

Does not yield the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already a standard function called `mapslices`, looks like exactly what you need.

```
julia> mapslices(sum, ones(4, 4), dims = 2)
4-element Vector{Float64}:
 4.0
 4.0
 4.0
 4.0
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.mapslices) or by typing `?` followed by `mapslices` in REPL.

If in your example you want to use the dot notation you should pass an array of rows, not the array itself. Otherwise, `sum` is applied to each element resulting in the same matrix. It can be done with `eachrow` and `eachcol` for rows and columns respectively.

```
julia> sum.(eachrow(ones(4, 4)))
4-element Vector{Float64}:
 4.0
 4.0
 4.0
 4.0
```

EDIT: I tried to suggest a more general solution, but if you have this option I would recommend using Andre's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the `dims` argument on a lot of functions that deal with sets of values.

```
sum([1 2; 3 4], dims=2)
2×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 3
 7

# or
using Statistics

mean([1 2; 3 4], dims=1)
1×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 2.0  3.0
```